# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentIn}: .support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I am trying to implement an Android app using the Support library for the ActionBar.

I came across the following error when compiling:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.coderzheaven.gcmdemo/com.gcmdemo.ChatActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gcmdemo.ChatActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
```

Can someone please give me an insight on this issue?

Comment: i am finding this error in log cat plz tell me the solution ..thank you..

Comment: Are you importing the correct ActionBarActivity class in your ChatActivity?

Comment: Could you organise a bit more your question, formatting and adding the correspondent code that throws this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `ChatActivity` as

```
public class ChatActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

    ....

}
```

You have derived it from either `FragmentActivity` or `Activity`